When a user deletes their account what happens to our rep?
Due to two recent user accounts being deleted, I wanted to ask this question. I am sure this is on StackOverflow Meta, but thought it might be valuable to have here.
When a user deletes their account what happens to our rep?

I think it depends on how many votes they've cast. If they've cast just a few votes, the rep gets removed. If they've cast a lot of votes, the rep stays.

This post might be relevant. But losing 110 rep when a person leaves does not surprise me.

It comes down to votes, and votes need to be owned by someone in order to persist in the system. When a user is removed, their votes are also nullified. This isn't the case in a merge where one account is technically deleted in the process, since the votes can just change ownership to the target user.
It's a bit of a contentious point, but that's how it works right now.
